# Instantiate the LAZY relationship prior to serialization

Tags: java, jpa

I have in VStateBE something like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "vState", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<VOptionBE> vOptions;

@Override
public Set<String> getSaList() {

    if (saList == null) {
        saList = new TreeSet<String>();
        for (final VOptionBE option : vOptions) {
            saList.add(normalizeSACode(option.getSa()));
        }
    }
    return saList;
```

and in the other class VOptionBE I have:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "SA", length = 4)
private String sa;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "V_SHORT")
private VStateBE vState;
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7242] (Eclipse Persistence Services -  2.3.4.v20130626-0ab9c4c): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: An attempt was made to traverse a relationship using indirection that had a null Session.  This often occurs when an entity with an  uninstantiated LAZY relationship is serialized and that lazy relationship is traversed after serialization.  To avoid this issue, instantiate the LAZY relationship prior to serialization.
```

It happens when it tries to read from the getSaList() method.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to find out WHY (de)serialization happens as this type of error is not often seen in common usecases. The most common solution would then be to preload all data before.

Anyway, if you want to **ensure** that lazy data is always loaded before serialization, it might help to implement your own serialization method on `VStateBE` class to load lazy collections before object is serialized. Just write your own [writeObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/output.html#a861) method, something like this:

```
@Entity
public class VStateBE implements Serializable {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "vState", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Set<VOptionBE> vOptions;

  // add method like this:
  private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream stream)
        throws IOException {
    vOptions.isEmpty(); // this will load lazy data in a portable way
    stream.defaultWriteObject(); // this will continue serializing your object in usual way
  }
}
```